# Supremum of infimum of measure of members of a free ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters

For a set $A\subseteq \omega$ we let the *upper density* of $A$ be defined as $d^+(A) := \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap(n+1)|}{n+1}$. Let $\text{FrU}(\omega)$ be the collection of [free ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\omega$.

[Asaf Karagila](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7206/asaf-karagila) provided a convincing argument that there is a free ultrafilter ${\cal U}$ on $\omega$ such that $d^+(U) > 0$ for all $U\in {\cal U}$.

**Question.** What is $$\sup\big\{\inf \{d^+(U): U \in {\cal U}\}: {\cal U} \in \text{FrU}(\omega)\big\}\;?$$

Comment: This is not Soviet Russia. We are not "Comrades" or "Users". Asaf Karagila, or just Asaf if the context is clear, would suffice. :-)

Comment: Apologies - will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is: zero.

The reason is that every ultrafilter has zero as the infimum of the upper density of its members. To see this, observe that if a set $U$ is in the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$, with some positive upper density, then we can split $U$ in half $U=A\sqcup B$ each with half the upper density (just take every other element of $U$ into $A$, the others into $B$). One of these sets will be in the ultrafilter, and so we will have a set in $\mathcal{U}$ with half the upper density of $U$. By iterating this, we can make the upper density of the sets in $\mathcal{U}$ as low as desired, so the infimum over the members is zero.

Comment: Or: every ultrafilter contains, for every $n$, a set of density $\frac1n$: just Take $X(n,i)=\{k:k\equiv i\pmod n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
If $u$ is an ultrafilter then for every $n$ there is an $i$ such that $X(n,i)\in u$.